# How to open links in new window which is in PDF created by TCPDF

Tags: php, html, target, tcpdf

I have tried `target="_blank"` but nothing happens. Is anybody help for this issue? I need to open links in new tab/window which is in PDF file.

I'm using `TCPDF 5.9.176`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TCPDF open links in new tab/window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15742922/tcpdf-open-links-in-new-tab-window)

Comment: @Tristanisginger 
No. I have tried the JS-solution. The javascript opens the target - but again in the same tab/window.

Comment: In short it is not possible here is SO answer that clarifies.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39763562/1695062

Answer (score 0):

Try using javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">function abrirVentana(url) {
window.open(url, "nuevo");
}
</script>
```

and then the HTML:

```
<a href="#" onClick="abrirVentana('http://')"></a>
```

Comment: So, how to use this code in TCPDF ? Have you ever tried something like that ?

Comment: I tried this together with spipu/html2pdf and I did not find a working solution. The javascript opened the target, but again in the same tab/window.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">function openExternal(){
if(!document.getElementsByTagName) return;
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName(’a');
for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++){
    var thisAnchor = anchors[i];
    if(thisAnchor.getAttribute(’href’) && thisAnchor.getAttribute(’rel’) == ‘external’){
        thisAnchor.target = ‘_blank’;
    }
 }
}

window.onload = openExternal;
</script>
<a href="http://" rel=”external”></a>
```