# TCPDF open links in new tab/window

Tags: javascript, php, html, tcpdf

How to open links in new tab/window which is in pdf document. I tried `target="_blank"` but it did not work. I was found `javascript` solution on the internet. But how I can use `javascript` in tcpdf.

I tried the following:

```
$text = 'bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla<br>';
$url = "http://google.com";
$links = ' <a href="javascript:open_win('.$url.');">Click me</a> 
           <a href="'.$url.'" target="_blank">Click me</a> ';

$output = $text.$links; $pdf->writeHTML($output);
```

But it did not work.

Comment: show me you code and what have you done so far?

Comment: `$text = 'bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla<br>';`
`$url = "http://google.com";`
`$links = '
     <a href="javascript:open_win('.$url.');">Click me</a> 
     <a href="'.$url.'" target="_blank">Click me</a>
';`
  
`$output = $text.$links;`
`$pdf->writeHTML($output);`

Comment: I cant give break for lines. It's looking complicated. Problem; I have 2 links in pdf but these are not opens in new window. I tried `javascript` and `target="_blank"`

Comment: Is it okay for you if it accomplished by html or you must need a javascript solution?

Comment: I prefer HTML solution. But If not, I can use javascript.

Comment: Do you see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524180/how-to-open-links-in-new-window-which-is-in-pdf-created-by-tcpdf

Comment: @namjoo I have tried. The JavaScript opens the target, but again in the same tab/window.

Comment: @SarahTrees i tried this and it worked.
<a href="a.pdf" target="_blank" rel="rel">link</a>

Answer (score 1):

use the below method

```
<a href="javascript: w=window.open('yoursite.com/LinkToThePDF.pdf'); w.print(); w.close(); ">​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​print pdf</a>
```

Comment: I know using javascript normally. How can I add functions into TCPDF ? That's the point of my problem.

Comment: <a href="javascript: w=window.open('http://yoursite.com/LinkToThePDF.pdf'); w.print(); w.close(); ">​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​print pdf</a>

Comment: @YasinYörük : If this solves ur problem mark it as answer.  Then only this question will close.

Comment: I have tried this solution. The javascript opens the target - but again in the same tab/window.

Answer (score 0):

you can open a the pdf by adding a *target="_blank"* in your form method

```
<form method="post" target="_blank">
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In short it is not possible here is SO answer that clarifies.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39763562/1695062